# What is the 'Install Summary' part of the Dashboard summary mean?

Tags: branch.io

[image: Part in question]

I neither understand what the 'Total' nor the 'Total untracked' mean. Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

The Install summary Pie chart gives you the total number of installs through Branch links. The pie chart shows the division based on Channel, Feature, Tags and Campaign (this segragation is based on the analytics tags you add you your Branch links.).

`Total Untracked` shows the installs for your App from non-Branch sources (for e.g. organic installs)

[image: Pie chart]

As shown in the Pie chart above,

1. There are a total of 46 installs from Branch links during the time period selected on the dashboard
2. Of these 46, 32 are from links which have channel set to 'Google Adwords', 4 from links with channel 'Copy to clipboard' and so on.
3. The total untracked: 65 is the number of installs from non-Branch sources.